Ignoring safe area prevents button click
I have a custom view where there are 3 pages: Blue, Red, and Green. Each page is the full width of the screen and I use an edge drag gesture to move between them. The initial view is the center Red one.
If I move to the Blue or Green pages and either: Open a .sheet fully or open the keyboard, then the Red middle page is no longer clickable. However, the left and right pages still are clickable.
Why does opening a sheet or using the keyboard make the center Red page unclickable? Removing all the ignore safe areas fixes the issue, but I need them.
Putting the navigation stack at the very top of the view also fixes it, but I do not want that. Removing all the ignore safe areas from within the navigation stack also fixes it, but I want them. A very odd behavior is if your in the defect state with the keyboard is shown and you swipe to the center page while the keyboard is displayed, then the center page becomes clickable again.
To reproduce:
edge swift on the right -> make textfield focused -> edge swipe back -> button should not be clickable (defect)
Code is copy-paste able.
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var option: Int = 2
    @State var lastStoredOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState var gestureOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 0.7
    @State var content: Bool = false
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            // PAGE ONE
            ZStack {
                Color.blue
                    .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true))
                    .scaleEffect(scale)
            }
            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            // DIVIDER
            Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea().frame(width: 13)
            
            //PAGE 2 WITH DEFECT
            NavigationStack {
                ZStack {
                    Color.red
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Button").font(.title)
                    })
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
           
            //DIVIDER
            Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea().frame(width: 13)
 
            //PAGE 3           
            ZStack {
                Color.green
                TextField("insert", text: $text)
            }
            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .offset(x: offset)
        .simultaneousGesture (
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged({ value in
                        let width = widthOrHeight(width: true)
                        let width2 = width * 2
                        
                        if option == 2 {
                            if (value.startLocation.x >= (width + 13) && value.startLocation.x <= (width + 28)) || (value.startLocation.x >= (width2 - 2.0) && value.startLocation.x <= (width2 + 13)) {
                                offset = value.translation.width + lastStoredOffset
                            }
                        } else if option == 1 {
                            if value.translation.width < 0 {
                                offset = value.translation.width + lastStoredOffset
                            }
                        } else {
                            if value.translation.width > 0 {
                                if value.startLocation.x >= (width + 13) && value.startLocation.x <= (width + 28.0) {
                                    offset = value.translation.width + lastStoredOffset
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        let ratio = (abs(offset) / width) * 0.3
                        scale = 0.7 + min(0.3, max(0.0, ratio))
                })
                .onEnded({ value in
                        let width = widthOrHeight(width: true)
                        
                        if option == 1 {
                            if offset < (width * 0.6) || value.velocity.width < -400.0 {
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                    offset = 0
                                    scale = 0.7
                                }
                                lastStoredOffset = 0
                                option = 2
                            } else {
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                    offset = width + 13
                                    scale = 1.0
                                }
                                lastStoredOffset = width + 13
                            }
                        } else if option == 2 {
                            let leftstart: Bool = (abs(value.startLocation.x - width) < 100.0)
                            
                            if (offset > (width * 0.4) || value.velocity.width > 400.0) && leftstart {
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                    offset = width + 13
                                    scale = 1.0
                                }
                                lastStoredOffset = width + 13
                                option = 1
                                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                            } else if (offset < -(width * 0.4) || value.velocity.width < -400.0) && !leftstart {
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                    offset = -width - 13
                                    scale = 1.0
                                }
                                lastStoredOffset = -width - 13
                                option = 3
                                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                            } else {
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                    offset = 0
                                    scale = 0.7
                                }
                                lastStoredOffset = 0
                            }
                        } else {
                            let isEdge: Bool = value.startLocation.x >= (width + 13) && value.startLocation.x <= (width + 28.0)
                            if offset > -(width * 0.6) || (value.velocity.width > 400.0 && isEdge) {
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                    offset = 0
                                    scale = 0.7
                                }
                                lastStoredOffset = 0
                                option = 2
                            } else {
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                                    offset = -width - 13
                                    scale = 1.0
                                }
                                lastStoredOffset = -width - 13
                            }
                        }
                })
            
        )
    }
}

func widthOrHeight(width: Bool) -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    if width {
        return window?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
    } else {
        return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
    }
}

#Preview {
    MainView()
}


func top_Inset() -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    return window?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0
}

func bottom_Inset() -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    return window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
}


The solution I found was applying a .zIndex(1) to the first and third page, while applying a .zIndex(500) to the middle page. It seems like the keyboard influences the safe area so combining NavigationStacks and IgnoreSafeAreas can cause issues.
